# Update window data. WPF

Tags: wpf, module, prism, reload

I have a WPF project with PRISM. In my bootstrapper I have following code.

```
      protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
      {
        Form1 form1= new Form1();
        Form2 form2= new Form2();

        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        mainWindow.Show();
        mainWindow.Activate();


        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(form1, this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>());
        RegionManager.SetRegionManager(form2, this.Container.Resolve<IRegionManager>());
        RegionManager.UpdateRegions();

        return mainWindow;
    }

    protected override IModuleCatalog GetModuleCatalog()
    {
        var moduleCatalog = new ModuleCatalog();
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(MainModule));
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(Form1Module), InitializationMode.OnDemand);
        moduleCatalog.AddModule(typeof(Form2Module), InitializationMode.OnDemand);
        return moduleCatalog;
    }
```

On MainForm I have `ListBox` and button. When we select some item in the `ListBox` and click "Show" button the form1 is shown with some data and the mainWindow is hidden. Form1 also has button "Go to Main", when user clicks it I do `form1.Hide()` (hide form1 with data) and `mainWindow.Show()` (again show mainWindow).On mainWindow user selects another item from the `ListBox` and clicks "Show" - the form1 is shown and it should display new data because user selected new item on mainWindow but form1 displays old data (data which was shown when module for form1 was loaded for the first time).

Example - on mainWindow we have the ListBox with the list of offices of some company, we select "Office1" and click "Show", this mainWindow hides and form1 loads, form1 displays the expenses list for "Office1". When I select another office on mainWindow, e.g. "Office2" form1 should display expenses for "Office2" but it displays expenses for "Office1".

I do moduleManager.LoadModule("") when user clicks "Show" button on mainWindow. I found the information that we can't reload module, it means the module is loaded only when we click "Show" button for the first time, but how can we update the data on the view?

Comment: It may just be me, but your question is a bit hard to follow.  Try to break it up into paragraphs and add some more detail about how you get your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I completely follow, but I will take a stab at this.

CreateShell should be for your main window only.  Prism uses this to setup the very first window for the application.  The only reason I have seen to make more than one visual window in here is for a splash screen.

So have CreateShell make your MainWindow.  Then, have MainWindow create your other forms as needed.  If you need new data each time, you can `new` them up each time.

The LoadModule part of your question is also a bit confusing.  The ModuleManager is a way to allow you to get parts of your application without needing a hard reference it.

Comment: I have changed the CreateShell, now I create only mainWindow. But when I create Form1 and try to loadModule "Module1"  via ModuleManager I get an Exception that "The region could not be found".
In Debug Mode I see that regionManager contain regions only for mainWindow, there is no region which is placed on my Form1.

Comment: Before load module i do
`code` var regionManager = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRegionManager>();
RegionManager.SetRegionManager(MyForm, regionManager);`code`
and it solved my problem.